# Pocketsphinx: App doesnt start

Tags: android, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

i got a problem with PocketSphinx, whenever i execute that Code, the app automatically shuts down. As i already try to figure out why it doesnt work for hours , maybe someone can help me? :)
so far the code looks like this,

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

    public SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try
        {
            Assets assets = new Assets(MainActivity.this);
            File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
            setupRecognizer(assetDir);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

    }
```

setupRecognizer:

```
private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir)
    {

        try {
            recognizer = defaultSetup()
                    .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                    .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
                    .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1e-20f)
                    .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)
                    .getRecognizer();
            recognizer.addListener(this);
            recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch("keywordsearch", "oh mighty Computer");
            recognizer.startListening("keywordsearch");

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

onPartialResult:

```
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hyp) {

    if (hyp == null) {

    }
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewcontrol);
    t.setText("found");
    recognizer.cancel();

}
```

maybe it helps: so far the app starts (=>does nothing but showing a textview) when i comment those lines out:

```
            recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch("keywordsearch", "oh mighty Computer");
            recognizer.startListening("keywordsearch");
```

when i only comment one of them out, it doesnt work.

so probably there is the mistake? I tried to import everything like in the tutorialcode for android, but i could also made a mistake there too.

thank you,

Jannis

Comment: Never ignore the exceptions. Try to `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Computer must be in lowercase. "oh mighty computer"

Comment: thank you a lot guys, lowercase was the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "recognizer.cancel();" from onPartialResult method use it when your app is closing.

```
public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.shutdown();
    }
```